# CoreData: error: NSFetchedResultsController: no object at index 0 in section at index 0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I don't understand why coredata is throwing this error, I am trying to fetch data from plist and getting this error again and again.

```
private func configureFetchedRresultsController(key : String, entity : String) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetechedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetechedResultsController?.delegate = self
    do {
        try fetechedResultsController?.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     guard let sections = fetechedResultsController?.sections else {
        return 0
    }

    let rowCount = sections[section].numberOfObjects
    return rowCount

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
    if let cat = fetechedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) as? Categories {
         cell.categoryName.text = cat.category
        cell.categoryImg.image = image1
     cell.categoryName.text = cat.desc
        //cell.categoryDes.text = catogries[indexPath.item].desc

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest to re-read some NSFetchedResultsController sample code. Returning the fixed number 5  as number of items in a section is wrong, and makes your program  crash if the fetch request returns less than 5 items.

Comment: I am sure the fetch request is 6 items i changed number to 6 also

Comment: I changed my count but now app is not loading anything @MartinR

Comment: That means that there are no objects fetched. What does `print(fetechedResultsController!.fetchedObjects.count)` print? – And btw, what does *“I am trying to fetch data from plist”* mean? A fetched results  controller  fetches objects from a Core Data database, not from a plist.

Comment: oh! I'm sorry first i am loading data from plist to coredata and then from core data to my app @MartinR

Comment: printing just says optional 0

Comment: So your fetch resulted in 0 items being fetched. You should check your code that is creating the core data entries